# Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code which gives me error as

> Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

```
if (reader.Read())
            {
                return reader.GetString(0);
            }
            return null;
```

Below is the full code

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentToBin(string ToBin, int warehouseId)
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConn"].ToString();
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
         const string queryString = "exec sp_P_WMS_Stock_Adj_Validation_Proc @Bin , @warehouse";

            var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString , conn);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bin",ToBin);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@warehouse", warehouseId);

            conn.Open();
            var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                return reader.GetString(0);
            }
            return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: @nad  can you please share the output of the exec proc

Comment: exec sp_P_WMS_Stock_Adj_Validation_Proc  . run it on sql server please and show the o/p

Comment: @GrantWinney: this line gives error `return reader.GetString(0);` value is `NULL`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it for null values like

```
if(!reader.IsDBNull(0))
  return reader.GetString(0);
```

Or use the method below

```
public string GetString(SqlDataReader reader, int columnIndex)
{
   if(!reader.IsDBNull(columnIndex))
       return reader.GetString(columnIndex);
   return string.Empty;
}
```

like this

```
return GetString(reader, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check with IsDBNull first.

For example see msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx